Capacitance multiplier as a reservoir capacitor
I came across a transistor based circuit called a capacitance multiplier, shown below. Many power supply projects use this circuit, on the top of a large reservoir capacitor (2200uF or 4700uF or 6800uF and so on.) Such designs piqued my curiosity as to why not replace the large value reservoir capacitor for a single capacitance multipler, or even a Darlington based one.

According to Jasen Слава Україні in this answer (edited by
Daniele Tampieri) to the question: "Capacitance multiplier or parallel capacitors for ultralow noise power supply" posted on Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange, licensed under CC BY-SA 4.0 quoted below:

A capacitance multiplier is a type of series regulator it does not store (much) energy.




Can someone explain me why they don't store enough energy to work as a reservoir capacitor?

"capacitance multiplier" should be purged from the world as a term - alongside with "ground". Think of this circuit as a "series resistance attenuator" instead and you will have multiplied your understanding. Personally, I call it "ripple eater", because it turns supply ripple into heat. It has good power supply rejection ratio, but bad output impedance, so it is useful for constant loads on a noisy supply.

Hi there Gabriel. The answers below focus on various (valid) effects, but are actually all derivatives of the "Miller Effect". Just start with wikipedia - "Miller Effect" or "Theorem". The Miller Effect exhibits in various ways, some good, some bad. Miller Effect caps are used eg. in integrated circuits, where you do not have space for physically large capacitors. However, the noise to be filtered must fit inside the amplifier's effective bandwidth! Also, you are not storing the same amount of charge as a physical cap, you are using the gain to present multiplied impedance to input, in band.

You can consider the circuit to be a low-pass filter formed by R1 and C1, followed by an emitter-follower Q1, to buffer the signal from the filter:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
When there is a sudden change in \$V_{IN}\$, base potential \$V_B\$ doesn't change immediately, due to the filter R1 & C1. However, the response by transistor Q1 is very different between \$V_{IN}\$ rising and \$V_{IN}\$ falling. This is because Q1 is able to limit current into load RL, to prevent potential \$V_{OUT}\$ rising, but it cannot sink current, and is unable to raise \$V_{OUT}\$ when \$V_{IN}\$ falls.
This means that in response to a fast rise in input \$V_{IN}\$, \$V_B\$ rises much more slowly, and \$V_{OUT}\$ follows nicely (albeit 0.8V or so lower, due to Q1's \$V_{BE}\$):

The most important consideration, though, in relation to the "energy" question, is that the potential difference \$V_{OUT}-V_{IN}\$ is "taken up" by transistor Q1, which means that Q1 is dissipating power while \$V_{OUT}\$ catches up:

Power being delivered to Q1 is energy lost as heat. That energy is not being stored in the capacitor, as it would have if you employed a real huge capacitor instead of this capacitance multiplier "hack". It is energy that can never be recovered, because C1 certainly didn't receive it. This has consequences when instead of a rise of \$V_{IN}\$, there's a sudden fall:

As before, \$V_B\$ falls much slower than \$V_{IN}\$ as intended, and you might expect the emitter-follower to follow as before, but since Q1 is not a source of energy (being unable to sink current here), it cannot maintain \$V_{OUT} \approx V_B\$ as it could during a rise of \$V_{IN}\$. Consequently \$V_{OUT}\$ plummets too.
This would not occur if we had employed a real RC filter:

simulate this circuit

In this case, some energy is lost in R1, but the capacitor really is storing energy when \$V_{IN}\$ rises, and is able to deliver it to the load, preventing \$V_{OUT}\$ from falling immediately when input voltage fails.
The capacitance multiplier is good when input fluctuations are small, and can prevent a lot of input noise from reaching OUT, but it doesn't perform well for large fluctuations. It can't store significant energy, since C1 is the only element that can do that. All the transistor can do is cut current through the load to keep \$V_{OUT}\$ from rising in spite of a rise of \$V_{IN}\$, but in doing so it throws away energy as heat.

The capacitance itself remains unchanged. However, the time behavior of the smaller capacitor is replicated by a more powerful, variable voltage source (emitter follower). When we refer to a "multiplied capacitor" , it's more accurate to think of it as a "virtual capacitor"  emulated by a voltage source. This technique is commonly used to create various virtual components; the gyrator (simulated inductor) is a prime example. See more in related answer of mine.
Memory
Reflecting on this phenomenon, a distant memory from the 70s resurfaced. My professor was unsuccessfully trying to mathematically explain the role of an op-amp in the famous inverting integrator circuit. After numerous transformations (I think there was even a Taylor series expansion), he concluded that, thanks to an op-amp with a gain of A, the capacitance of the capacitor in the negative feedback loop had increased A+1 times. No matter how hard I tried to grasp this brilliant idea, I couldn't imagine how physically the capacitor had become thousands of times larger:-) Much later, in the 90s, I simply explained to myself what the op-amp was doing - it was simply compensating for the voltage drop across the capacitor with an equivalent voltage. The capacitance of the capacitor remained the same, but the voltage across it was approximately zero, and the input source had the illusion that the capacitor had incredibly increased its capacitance.
This was my first encounter with virtual elements in electronic circuits. Since then, I have never ceased to be amazed by this unique circuit phenomenon.


So, can someone explain me why they don't store enough energy to work
as a reservoir capacitor?

A true reservoir capacitor can hold-up the incoming supply close to the normal peak voltage for a limited (but usually sufficient) length of time. A typical example is using a reservoir capacitor after a bridge rectifier. When the AC voltage drops below the peak charged voltage on the capacitor, the capacitor retains charge even though the bridge rectifier diodes are not supplying any energy.
A capacitance multiplier is an emitter follower and this means that  the emitter voltage (under moderate load) will be one diode drop below the collector voltage so, it has the disadvantage that it cannot deal with any significant voltage excursions on the incoming supply (whereas a true reservoir capacitor performs far, far better).
The energy stored in the capacitance multiplier is far lower than that stored in a true reservoir capacitor hence, it's a fairly useless circuit in many applications.
As always, there are places for capacitance multipliers but, these are few and far between.


explain me why they don't store enough energy to work as a reservoir capacitor?

Because no capacitance is actually multiplied.  The name "Capacitance Multiplier" is not a scientifically accurate and precise description of the circuit.  It's more like a loose slang term.
It's a circuit designed for a narrow set of uses, and the circuit's effect is to smooth the AC component of its input at a higher level of output current than the specified capacitor could do by itself.  It simulates the effect of a larger value capacitor in that specific situation.  Being a limited simulation, it doesn't have all the same characteristics of an actual larger value capacitor - such as energy storage.

That circuit cannot alone replace a reservoir cap, because the so called "capactance multiplier" needs DC in that is always higher than the input to work, and this requires that the AC is rectified to DC into a suitably large reservoir capacitor first.
You could simply rename the "capacitance multiplier" as being an "RC filter with emitter follower pass transistor" to buffer the RC filtered smoother voltage so that the load does not directly have the ripply resevoir capacitor voltage on it.


Can someone explain me why they don't store enough energy to work as a reservoir capacitor?

Because the energy stored in the base capacitor is available to the load only through the transistor base-emitter junction.  This junction is not designed to be a power-path component; that is for the collector-emitter structure.  For example, a transistor might be rated for a 20 A collector (and emitter) current, but the max. base current spec is much lower.
Also, there is no voltage or current gain from the base to the emitter when the base-emitter junction is treated as a simple diode.  Thus, the only energy available to the output is that stored in the cap; there is no "multiplication" effect.  You get the same overall performance as if there were no transistor.
The "capacitor multiplier" circuit is all about ripple reduction.  R1-C1 form a single-pole lowpass filter, and the transistor acts as a power amplifier (actually, a current amplifier).

That's not entirely correct; the energy stored in the capacitor surely can flow back through R1.
